# Ошибка при попытке получить данные из БД

Tags: java, sqlite3

При попытке обратиться к бд и получить от неё данные получаю следующую ошибку:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pizzaometelly, PID: 8207
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5689)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26104)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5684)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26104) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM  SELECT * FROM pizzaOrders
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
        (near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM  SELECT * FROM pizzaOrders)
    #################################################################
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1096)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:661)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1746)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1593)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1464)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1632)
        at com.example.pizzaometelly.AdminPage.Refresh(AdminPage.java:40)
```

Сама активность, где я пытаюсь обратиться к бд:

```java
public class AdminPage extends Activity {

    WorkBD workBD;
    private Cursor cursor;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.admin_page);
        workBD = new WorkBD(this);
    }

    public void Refresh(View v){
        SQLiteDatabase db = workBD.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query(" SELECT * FROM " + WorkBD.TABLE_CONTACTS, null,null,null,null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do{
            Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(cursor));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

активность отвечающая за бд:

```java
public class WorkBD extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "pizzaDb.db";
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "pizzaOrders";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_NUMBER = "number";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_PIZZA1 = "pizza1";
    public static final String KEY_PIZZA2 = "pizza2";
    public static final String KEY_PIZZA3 = "pizza3";
    public static final String KEY_PIZZA4 = "pizza4";
    public static final String KEY_PIZZA5 = "pizza5";
    public static final String KEY_COMMENT = "comment";
    public static final String KEY_ISCOOK = "iscook";
    public static final String KEY_ISDELIVER = "isdeliver";



    public WorkBD(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " (" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " + KEY_NUMBER + " TEXT, "+ KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT, " + KEY_PIZZA1 + " TEXT, " +  KEY_PIZZA2 + " TEXT, " + KEY_PIZZA3 + " TEXT, " + KEY_PIZZA4 + " TEXT, " + KEY_PIZZA5 + " TEXT, " + KEY_COMMENT + " TEXT, " + KEY_ISCOOK + " BLOB DEFAULT 0, "  + KEY_ISDELIVER + " BLOB DEFAULT 0" + " )");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

И активность где я наполняю бд:

```
public class BasketPage extends Activity {
 @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bascket_page);
        FinalBuy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buyText);
        mainActivity= new MainActivity();
        culculateFprice();
        workBD = new WorkBD(this);
        Recycler();
    }

    public void finish_check(View v){
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorview);
        EditText namik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText phonik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        EditText streetik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.street);
        EditText homeik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.home);
        EditText porchik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.porch);
        EditText levelik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.level);
        EditText apprtik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.room);
        EditText commentic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment);

        name = namik.getText().toString();
        t.setText("");


        if (name.equals("")){
            t.setText(getString(R.string.error_final));
            b = false;
        }

        phoneNumber = phonik.getText().toString();

        if (phoneNumber.equals("")){
            t.setText(getString(R.string.error_final));
            b = false;
        }

        street = streetik.getText().toString();

        if (street.equals("")){
            t.setText(getString(R.string.error_final));
            b = false;
        }

        home = homeik.getText().toString();

        if (home.equals("")){
            t.setText(getString(R.string.error_final));
            b = false;
        }

        porch = porchik.getText().toString();

        if (porch.equals("")){
            t.setText(getString(R.string.error_final));
            b = false;
        }

        level = levelik.getText().toString();


        if (porch.equals("")){
            t.setText(getString(R.string.error_final));
            b = false;
        }

        apprt = apprtik.getText().toString();


        if (apprt.equals("")){
            t.setText(getString(R.string.error_final));
            b = false;
        }

        comment = commentic.getText().toString();

        String address = "Улица: " + street + ", Дом:  " + home + ". Номер подъезда: " + porch + ". Этаж: " + level + ". Номер квартиры: " + apprt;


        if(b){
            SQLiteDatabase database = workBD.getReadableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_NAME , name);
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_NUMBER, phoneNumber);
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_ADDRESS, address);
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_PIZZA1, MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount());
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_PIZZA2, MainActivity.calzone.getCount());
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_PIZZA3, MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount());
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_PIZZA4, MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount());
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_PIZZA5, MainActivity.mexican.getCount());
            contentValues.put(WorkBD.KEY_COMMENT, comment);
            database.insert(WorkBD.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues);
        }
        Intent perehod = new Intent(BasketPage.this, LoginPage.class);
        startActivity(perehod);
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас невалидный SQL. В ошибке указано следующее: `SELECT * FROM  SELECT * FROM pizzaOrders`. Разберитесь как так вышло и ошибка (эта) пропадёт.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста уточнить что значит невалидный SQL.

Comment: Невалидно отсутствие скобок вокруг вложенного запроса. Т.е. верно будет такое: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM pizzaOrders)`, однако у вас тут, кажется, просто дублирующийся текст и вы хотели такое: `SELECT * FROM pizzaOrders`

Comment: удалите `" SELECT * FROM " +` из `db.query`, там первым аргументом должно быть только имя таблицы